# Sanity Studio commands not working and encountering syntax error on Mac M1 with Visual Studio Code - How to troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sanity

**Getting syntax error while accessing local host of sanity studio.**

> Uncaught error: The requested module '/schemas/testimonials.js' does not provide an export named 'testimonials'
> http://localhost:3333/schemas/index.js:1:9
> SyntaxError: The requested module '/schemas/testimonials.js' does not provide an export named 'testimonials'

My index.ts

```
import testimonials from './testimonials'
export const schemaTypes = [testimonials]
```

My testimonials.js

```
export default
{
    name: 'testimonials',
    title: 'Testimonials',
    type: 'document',
    fields:
    [
        {
            name: 'name',
            title: 'Name',
            type: 'String'
        },
        {
            name: 'company',
            title: 'Company',
            type: 'String'
        },
        {
            name: 'imageurl',
            title: 'ImgURL',
            type: 'image',
            options:
            {
                hotspot : true,
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'feedback',
            title: 'Feedback',
            type: 'String'
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to run sanity studio on mac m1 using visual studio code but getting too much troubles like the commands for example sanity help, sanity start etc doesn't work and now this syntax error.